# Не могу вызвать перегрузку

Tags: c++

Продолжаю пробовать перегружать операторы, и вновь не могу вызвать перегрузку.
Например, есть класс List:

```
class List
{
    Node *first;
    Node *end;
    int *count;
public:
    List()
    {
        first = NULL;
        end = NULL;
        count = new int(0);
    }
    ~List()
    {
        delete count;
    }
    void Add(Branch *ptr)
    {
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first = end = new Node();
            first->prev = NULL;
            first->item = ptr;
            first->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            end->next = new Node();
            end = end->next;
            end->item = ptr;
            end->next = NULL;
        }
        *count = *count + 1;
    }
    Branch* operator[](int i)
    {
        if (!(i < *count))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        Node *temp = first;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            j++;
        }
        return temp->item;
    }
    void Set(int i, Branch* ptr)
    {
        if (!(i < *count))
        {
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = first;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            j++;
        }
        temp->item = ptr;
    }
    void Delete(int i)
    {
        if (!(i < *count))
        {
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = first;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            j++;
        }
        if (temp == first)
        {
            first = first->next;
            first->prev = NULL;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if (temp == end)
        {
            end = end->prev;
            end->next = NULL;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
            temp->prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        count--;
    }
    int Count()
    {
        return *count;
    }
};
```

В нём перегружен оператор =;

Если я вызываю из Main()

```
int main()
{
    List *wow = new List;
    cout << (*wow)[0]->node_to; //выведет 1;
}
```

Идём дальше, объявляем класс Graph

```
class Graph
{
public:
    List *branhes;
    Graph()
    {
branches = new List();
}
};
```

В main объявляем:

```
int main()
{
Graph *graph = new Graph();
graph->branches[0]; //ссылается на сам список, а не на перегрузку
}
```

Вот в чём вопрос, как вызывать перегрузку при таком объявлении из объекта? 
Извиняюсь, если тупой вопрос, поиском воспользовался, может искать не умею, но ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(*graph->branches)[i]` (или `graph->branches[0][i]`).

---

Кроме того, во-первых: Зачем вы используете указатели и `new`/`delete` там, где они не нужны? Раз: `int *count;` `count = new int(0);`. Два: `List *branhes;` `Graph *graph = new Graph();` Можно ведь просто сделать `int count;` и `List branches;`.

Во вторых: Ваш `~List()` вызывает утечку памяти. Кто будет удалять содержимое списка?

В третьих: Поскольку `List` нарушает [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), он совершенно не подходит для использования в настоящих программах. Он ломается даже от `List a, b; a = b;`.

<sup>Когда будете приводить класс в соответствие с the rule of three, вам может пригодиться это: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)</sup>

Comment: Благодарю за помощь с использованием перегрузки.

Comment: Преподаватель требует использование new и delete, даже там где они не нужны, касательно утечки памяти согласен, ибо List ещё не дописан. The rule of three в контексте данной программы не имеет смысла реализовывать, опять же из-за требований преподавателя, Однако полезные замечание на будущее, спасибо!

Comment: Как обычно, самым важным вещам не учат. :/